# Convert XML to CSV with XSLT

Tags: xml, csv, xslt, xslt-1.0

I'd like to convert XML into CSV using an XSLT.Could please someone help me to rearrange the XSL file so that each data, if it exists, is correctly stored in the columns according to the header. Otherwise the column must remain empty.

My inputs are

XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<message version="2.0" system="avs/3"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <header>
        <creation-date>2016-10-06</creation-date>
        <creation-time>10:46:00</creation-time>
    </header>
    <body>
        <subscription>
            <promotion-source>5011158916</promotion-source>
            <publication>00069329</publication>
            <business-partner id="" role-type="AG">
                <company1>AM</company1>
                <company2>Gebug</company2>
                <company3></company3>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>T</communication-type>
                    <communication-value></communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>F</communication-type>
                    <communication-value></communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>WW</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>mm@hvhv.de</communication-value>
                </communication>
            </business-partner>
            <business-partner id="Doc" role-type="WE">
                <last-name1>M</last-name1>
                <first-name>A</first-name>
                <street>str.</street>
                <zipcode>33</zipcode>
                <company1>PM</company1>
                <company2>Geung</company2>
                <company3></company3>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>T</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>0883</communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>F</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>608</communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>WW</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>BIN@online.de</communication-value>
                </communication>
                <attribute>
                    <attribute-type>EMNL</attribute-type>
                    <attribute-value>N</attribute-value>
                </attribute>
            </business-partner>
        </subscription>
        <subscription>
            <promotion-source>916</promotion-source>
            <publication>329</publication>
            <business-partner id="Mas" role-type="AG">
                <company1>iß</company1>
                <company2>mp; Co.</company2>
                <company3></company3>
            </business-partner>
            <business-partner id="" role-type="WE">
                <last-name1>ar</last-name1>
                <first-name>ro</first-name>
                <street>str</street>
                <zipcode>858</zipcode>
                <company1>mp;iß</company1>
                <company2>mp;G</company2>
                <company3></company3>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>T</communication-type>
                    <communication-value></communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>F</communication-type>
                    <communication-value></communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>WW</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>p@m.de</communication-value>
                </communication>
                <attribute>
                    <attribute-type>L</attribute-type>
                    <attribute-value>N</attribute-value>
                </attribute>
            </business-partner>
        </subscription>
        <subscription>
            <promotion-source>916</promotion-source>
            <publication>009</publication>
            <business-partner id="Mas" role-type="AG">
                <company1>ten</company1>
                <company2>GR</company2>
                <company3></company3>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>T</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>061</communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>F</communication-type>
                    <communication-value></communication-value>
                </communication>
                <communication>
                    <communication-type>WW</communication-type>
                    <communication-value>alff@a-h-architekten.de</communication-value>
                </communication>
            </business-partner>
            <business-partner id="Doc" role-type="WE">
                <last-name1>zek</last-name1>
                <first-name>Ht</first-name>
                <street>Pt</street>
                <zipcode>62</zipcode>
                <company1>ten</company1>
                <company2>GR</company2>
                <company3></company3>
                <attribute>
                    <attribute-type>L</attribute-type>
                    <attribute-value>N</attribute-value>
                </attribute>
            </business-partner>
        </subscription>
    </body>
</message>
```

And here is the xsl stylesheet file:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
<xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output the CSV header -->
    <xsl:text>promotion-source;publication;BP-id;BP-role-type;AG-last-name;AG-first-name;AG-company1;AG-company2;AG-company3;AG-tel;AG-fax;AG-email;BP-id;BP-role-type;WE-last-name;WE-first-name;WE-street;WE-zipcode;WE-company1;WE-company2;WE-company3;WE-tel;WE-fax;WE-email;attribute-type;attribute-value&#10;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Output the value -->
    <xsl:for-each select="message/body/subscription">
        <!-- begin value -->
        <xsl:value-of select="concat(promotion-source, ';', publication,';')" />
        <!-- business-partner values -->
        <xsl:for-each select="business-partner">
            <xsl:value-of select="@id" />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of select="@role-type" />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
            <xsl:value-of
                select="concat(last-name1, ';', first-name, ';', street, ';', zipcode, ';', company1, ';', company2, ';', company3, ';')" />
            <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>

            <xsl:for-each select="communication">
                <xsl:value-of select="communication-value" />
            </xsl:for-each>

            <xsl:for-each select="attribute">
                <xsl:value-of select="attribute-type" />
                <xsl:text>;</xsl:text>
                <xsl:value-of select="attribute-value" />
            </xsl:for-each>
        </xsl:for-each>
        <xsl:text>
</xsl:text>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

I have all the wanted data in the Output file except that they are not stored in their respective columns and that is my problem.Your help is appreciated. :)

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want a flat list as output, therefore you can't use nested structures (for-each within for-each) to create it.

You seem to want to list business partners and their details, so your single loop should be focused on `<business-partner>` elements, and all the details should be picked relative to them.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" encoding="UTF-8" />
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <!-- Output the CSV header -->
    <xsl:text>promotion-source;publication;BP-id;BP-role-type;AG-last-name;AG-first-name;AG-company1;AG-company2;AG-company3;AG-tel;AG-fax;AG-email;BP-id;BP-role-type;WE-last-name;WE-first-name;WE-street;WE-zipcode;WE-company1;WE-company2;WE-company3;WE-tel;WE-fax;WE-email;attribute-type;attribute-value&#10;</xsl:text>

    <!-- Output the values -->
    <xsl:for-each select="//business-partner">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../promotion-source, ';')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(../publication, ';')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@id, ';')">
      <xsl:value-of select="concat(@role-type, ';')" />
      <!-- and so on -->

      <xsl:value-of select="concat(communication[communication-type = 'T']/communication-value, ';')" />
      <!-- and so on -->

      <xsl:value-of select="concat(attribute[attribute-type = 'EMNL']/attribute-value, ';')" />
      <!-- and so on -->

      <xsl:value-of select="'&#xA;' />
    </xsl:for-each>
  </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Output a single value per line of XSLT to keep things readable and tidy.

Comment: Dear Tomalak, Using the XSL stylesheet, I encounter a problem and I would like to ask for your help. I would like to set a condition so that the communication values are selected only if the business-partner "Role-type" is AG or WE. If  the columns must remain empty.

Comment: I'm sorry, I won't answer these kinds of follow-ups. You have a solution that works, you will need to take the time and learn enough about the basics of XSLT and XPath make that modification it on your own. It's not hard.

Answer (score 1):

The number of columns are differents for **business-partner AG** and for **business-partner WE** and you are using the same `for each` to concatenate these columns, that`s the reason why your columns doesn't match